# byte array to hex and revert back java

Tags: java

i have a byte array its value taken from debugger

```
0 = -124
1 = 56
2 = 56
3 = 65
```

then convert to hex

```
StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : Bytes) {
    res1.append(String.format("%02X-", b));
}
```

i get result 84-38-38-41

,i want to revert it back to same previous value like

if i have 84-38-38-41 ,how can i get the bytearray with the value

```
0 = -124
1 = 56
2 = 56
3 = 65
```

means hex string to decimal array

Comment: If you drop the '-' from your format, you can use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java. Or just modify it to skip the '-'.

Comment: thanks it works after modifying a bit

Answer (score 2):

Replaced all "-" with "" and this does your job. I hope this will help.

```
        byte [] data = {-124,56,56,24};
        StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : data) {
            res1.append(String.format("%02X-",b));
        }
        String new_String  = res1.toString().replaceAll("-", "");
        byte [] output = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(new_String);
        for(int i = 0;i < output.length;i++){
            System.out.println(output[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Byte[] to hex:**

```
public String getHex(byte[] raw) {
        final String HEXES = "0123456789abcdef";
        final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(2 * raw.length);
        for (final byte b : raw) {
            hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4)).append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
        }
        return hex.toString();
    }
```

**Hex to byte[]:***

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
```

And remember...
**Always practice safe hex!** (: